# How to form an array using series of dataset Id values you've collected from a div

Tags: javascript, arrays

[The dataset Id is attached to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/833hl.png)Let's say for instance I've attached dataset Id values to a series of div's and these values are different from one another, if I want to collect these values and form an array with them how do it do it?

I already tried looping through them since they are all divs with the same class name,but it gives me back the values on individual array and not collectively into one array. I can't use array.from() cos it would just turn the string into separate characters and form an array with them. What do you all suggest I do?

Comment: Your description is confusing.  Show us a code example that isn't working, and probably include the HTML you're working from.  I assume you know how to push vaiues onto an array one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can first select all the elements by class with `document.querySelectorAll`, then apply a mapping function to read the `dataset.id`.

```js
const res = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.a'), d => d.dataset.id);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<div data-id="100" class="a"></div>
<div data-id="101" class="a"></div>
<div data-id="102" class="a"></div>
```